# Why does list-iterator.next(); goes back to "no current element" position unless it is iterated multiple times till end?

Tags: java, linked-list, listiterator

According to Java documentation :

> A ListIterator has no current element; its cursor position always lies
>   between the element that would be returned by a call to previous() and
>   the element that would be returned by a call to next(). An iterator
>   for a list of length n has n+1 possible cursor positions, as
>   illustrated by the carets (^) below:

My question is, for example, suppose a while loop is runing and upon pressing 2, I call a method

```
public void callNextElement(int choice, LinkedList<String> linkedList) {

    ListIterator<String> listIterator = linkedList.listIterator();
    if (choice == 2) {
        if (listIterator.hasNext()){
            listIterator.next();
            System.out.println("We have: " + listIterator.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this would print the first element and go back to while loop to take input, now again pressing 2, I will get the first element/entry of list. And if I did :

```
System.out.println("We have: " + listIterator.next());
System.out.println("We have: " + listIterator.next());
System.out.println("We have: " + listIterator.next());
System.out.println("We have: " + listIterator.next());
....
```

This would print the other elements in the linked list

So my questions are :

1. Why doesn't it print out the 2nd element and so on in the method I called?
2. Why does it *only works* if listiterator.next() is called in a succession like I did by printing them above?
3. What happens if listiterator would actually store the next element position so that when even if  `next()` called (without succession) it would print the next element? Not the first one.

EDIT:

I feel so stupid but is it Java's garbage collection at work in my method call thing? If yes, then it makes sense why it prints 1st element each time. I'm new to Java and totally forgot about this...

Comment: Re edit: no, it has nothing to do with garbage collection. Is is only related to fact that each `linkedList.listIterator()` creates *new* list iterator with its own information about position (in this case it would be start of the list, so each `next()` on separate new list iterators would result in first element - assuming list is not empty).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every list iterator has its own independent position in the list. Every time you call `listIterator()` you get a *new* iterator that starts at the beginning of the list.

```
ListIterator<String> listIterator = linkedList.listIterator();
```

If you want to iterate over successive elements you need to call `listIterator()` once and save the iterator somewhere so it can be reused.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions you need to understand that `Iterator` remembers it's position in the `Collection` or `Iterable`, but only the same instance of an `Iterator` knows this position (i.e. how many time `Iterator.next()` has been called)

> 1) Why doesnt it print out the 2nd element and so on in the method i called?

```
ListIterator<String> listIterator = linkedList.listIterator();
```

In this line of your method you create a *new* `Iterator` for the list every time you call this method. The new `Iterator` will always start at the beginning of the list. That's why you'll always only get the first element of the list.

> 2)Why does it only works if listiterator.next() is called in a sucession ? like I did by printing them above.

As mentioned above a new iterator will always start at (or more correctly before) the first element of a list. By calling `Iterator.next()` you move the iterator to the next element of the list. If you call `next()` multiple times on the *same* `Iterator` you will move through the whole list until `Iterator.hasNext()` returns `false`. If `Iterator.hasNext()` is `false` and you continue calling `Iterator.next()` a `NoSuchElementException` will be thrown.

> 3) What happens if listiterator would actually store the next element position so that when even if next() called (without succession) it would print the next element ? Not the first one.

I think this has already been answered above?!

You could change your method to accept the `Iterator` itself as argument instead of the list like this:

```
public void callNextElement(int choice, ListIterator<String> listIterator) {
    if (choice == 2) {
        if (listIterator.hasNext()){
            listIterator.next()
            System.out.println("We have: " + listIterator.next());
        }
    }
}
```

This method would be called like this:

```
ListIterator<String> listIterator = linkedList.listIterator();
while (condition == true) {
    callNextElement(choice, listIterator);
}
```

This way you will always pass the *same* `Iterator` to the callNextElement method and successively advance this iterator's position.

And no, this has absolutely nothing to do with garbage collection.